# Sprite Kit remove restitution (bounce) on specific contact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody

I have a contact delegate set up for some objects in sprite kit, one is dynamic and one is not. The restitution of the dynamic object is set to 0.8 (fairly bouncy) is there a way that on this contact (and only this contact) that the dynamic object can not bounce at all. Ie, when it this this specific object it loses all its momentum.

I can set the restitution after this contact has taken place, so the next collision has less bounce, but not this one specifically. Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: set its velocity to 0,0 if you want it to stop

Comment: Simple! Thanks a lot. How about is i just want to reduce its velocity by like 90%? Am I going to have to look at calculating the angle it would bounce at and applying an impulse?